Nested list comprehension with conditions: how to generate a list and not a nested list
I'm parsing through a list in Python 3.7.9 that contains integers and strings. And I want to replace each string with the ASCII values of its chars.
As an example: operand = [200, 42, 0, 'A', 'BC'].
And the result I would like to have: operand = [200, 42, 0, 65, 66, 67]
The best I've come so far is this, where I redefine the list with nested comprehension:
operand = [[ord(char) for char in data] if type(data) is str else data for data in operand]

The problem is that it generates a mixed list: integers and nested lists of integers.
I would want to avoid flattening the list after.
How can I generate the correct list with nested comprehension?

... else [data] then flatten it.

Thank you. Indeed it works, although I would have liked to avoid flattening the list.

You want the list to be flattened without flattening the list?

No, I want to generate the list so I don't have to flatten it.

But you want to turn some of the entries in the first list into multiple elements, so some level of flattening is unavoidable.

Why a comprehension?

You can build a 1-level list directly, using a 2-level list-comprehension
operand = [
    item
    for data in operand
    for item in (map(ord, data) if isinstance(data, str) else [data])
]

Or, in a very different way
from itertools import chain

def to_ints(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        yield from map(ord, value)
    else:
        yield value

operand = list(chain.from_iterable(map(to_ints, operand)))

